# Unable to store cookies in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies, model-view-controller

LoginController:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
def new
    cookies[:id]=rand(1000)
    render "index"
end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<body>
    <center>
    <h1> Login </h1>
    <form action='login/auth' method='POST'>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" widht=20><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass" widht=20><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </center>
    <br><br>
</body>
```

My requirement is, if login page is called, the response page should send with a cookie. So, I create a cookie with a random number in
new action. But the page "index.html" didn't have cookie in browser. But it is properly worked if "new" action call its default view file
"new.html.erb". Why the cookie only works in default view and not in some other view file. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Is your new action being executed in both case?

Comment: @FrederickCheung What I meant is, I am able to access "cookies[]" only if the action and views are in the same name. For Ex: while submitting the form '/login/auth' then auth.html.erb is only worked. If we deliberately render some other page, then the cookies not goes with that page.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you have two typos in the form. "width" is typed as "widht."

```
<form action='login/auth' method='POST'>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" widht=20><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass" widht=20><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This won't solve the problem, but it will remove one more error once the problem is solved.

Related to the original problem, I wonder if it could be that when you want to pass a variable to a non-default view, you may need an instance variable (but since cookies aren't expressed as instance variables, I'm not sure where to go with that)

Comment: This is not related to the problem at all.

Comment: But as per the reference they specify only like "cookies[:id] = user.id".